# Compare specific date format in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex string and another string which I pass from a config file into my code.

```
a=daily_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}
b=YYYY_MM_DD
```

Examples can be: daily_2015_03_17, daily_2014_02_10....

Now I want to check if the string "a" has valid date format specified by string "b".

Please help me how to achieve this in Java.

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` for parsingf the string.

Comment: The string "a" can be modified any time like "today_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}" or "[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_daily". The only thing that will not change for sure is date inside string "a". Reason for not using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Then, do you want to validate the regex expression itself? If `a` string contains `[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}`?

Comment: Yes. Just want to compare if "a" contains regex format specified by "b".

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be(This doesn't check for leap years):

```
string b = (daily_)(\d{4}_)(((0[13578]|[1][02])_(0[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1]))|((0[469]|11)_(0[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|30))|(02_(0[1-9]|[1|2][0-9])));
a="daily_2015_03_30";
boolean res = a.matches(b);
//res says "true" if a match.
```